# Getting value from jsoncode using VB.net

Tags: jquery, .net, json, vb.net

## hello  I have this json code and I would like to get the value which is 21, black jack, tongits along with its score.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "status": "PARTIAL",
  "scores": [
    {
      "scoreCard": {
        "21": 0,
        "black jack": 0,
        "tongits": 0
      },
      "question": "Favorite game",
      "questionnaireId": 1
    },
    {
      "scoreCard": {
        "red": 0,
        "green": 0,
       "blue": 0,
        "black": 0
      },
      "question": "Favorite color",
      "questionnaireId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

## this is my vb code which I only get the value Favorite game and Favorite color

```
Dim webC As New System.Net.WebClient
     Dim json As String =webC.DownloadString("http://localhost:8080/report/survey/1/result")

    Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

    Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList

    For Each item As JProperty In results
        item.CreateReader()
        Select Case item.Name

            Case "scores"

                Dim question As String

                For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                    question = subitem("question")
                    Listview2.Items.Add(question)

                Next
        End Select
    Next
```

Comment: you could deserialize it in 1-2 lines of code

Comment: what exacly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easier to parse the data to get just one or two things:

```
Dim jstr = ...from where ever...

Dim jData = JObject.Parse(jstr)

Console.WriteLine(jData("scores")(0)("scoreCard")("21"))
Console.WriteLine(jData("scores")(0)("scoreCard")("black jack"))
Console.WriteLine(jData("scores")(0)("scoreCard")("tongits"))

Console.WriteLine(jData("scores")(0)("question"))
Console.WriteLine(jData("scores")(1)("question"))
```

`scores` is an array as indicated by the `[ ... ]` enclosure, so that needs to be indexed, otherwise just use the indentation and intellisence to fish out whatever you want.  Results:

> 0
>   0
>   0
>   Favorite game
>   Favorite color

However, since you are after 4 things at least: the 2 questions and 3 scores, it would be even easier to [deserialize the data to a class object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090483/1070452) and just get what you want from the properties.