# Deserializing json with nested dictionary

Tags: json, vb.net

I've gotten pretty far but ran into wall with this. Have JSON coming from a web API I am using.

Here is the Json string (or at least the first part)

```
{
  "id": "065f1b17-0b2c-47c1-9674-c2bfda8c05bc",
  "number": "167",
  "title": "SSF-5003 MC Checklist HVAC",
  "status": "open",
  "description": null,
  "shared": false,
  "items": 
  [
    {
      "id": "a31a2f92-e948-4563-809e-6faed67e5db3",
      "description": "Project Number",
      "type": "text-area",
      "comment": null,
      "issue": null,
      "response": {
        "value": "Az001",
        "responded_by": {
          "id": "1208055465",
          "organization": {
            "id": "1207960635",
            "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "trading_name": "xxxx"
          },
          "first_name": "Brett",
          "last_name": "VanDyke"
        },
        "responded_at": "2017-03-02T14:45:47.924Z"
      },
      "item_number": "1",
      "photo_url": null,
      "response_options": [ ]
    },
```

My two classes:

```
Public Class HVAC
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property number As Int64
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property items As hvac_item()
End Class

Public Class hvac_item
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property item_number As Int32
    Public Property response As Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

Main code deserliazing the json:

```
json_in = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetTempPath() & "\hvac.json")
Dim hvac = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of HVAC)(json_in)
```

If I comment out the "response" property I deserialize without any errors and see all info (except in the "response" section).

Cannot figure out how to get the dictionary information out. Think I might have to deserialize that within the hvac_item class but not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've been a member for almost 2 months, time to learn how to format code so it can be read.

Comment: Plutonix - yeah - was trying to remember how, answered someone else's question and saw the shortcut.

Comment: Look at my question - a little clarity here:  Trying to get "value" out of the "response" area (what I think is a dictionary object)

Comment: I dont think that will deserialize as a Dictionary(Of String, String) because `"responded_by":` is more than just a string.  Where did the classes come from?  VS will build (mostly correct) ones for you

Comment: I built the classes, didn't know VS will build them for me (really new to JSON) will look into that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42090483/1070452

Comment: [**Please do not put tags in the title**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: Be careful with Paste Special > JSON as Classes...for arrays, it puts the `()` in the wrong place. They should be at the end, after the type, not trailing the property name.

Answer (score 0):

These are my best guess at the classes I get from the incomplete JSON fragment provided...

```
Public Class HVAC
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property number As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property description As Object
    Public Property _shared As Boolean
    Public Property items As Item()
End Class

Public Class Item
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property comment As Object
    Public Property issue As Object
    Public Property response As Response
    Public Property item_number As String
    Public Property photo_url As Object
    Public Property response_options As Object()
End Class

Public Class Response
    Public Property value As String
    Public Property responded_by As Responded_By
    Public Property responded_at As Date
End Class

Public Class Responded_By
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property organization As Organization
    Public Property first_name As String
    Public Property last_name As String
End Class

Public Class Organization
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property trading_name As String
End Class
```

And to access the data....

```
Dim HVAC = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of HVAC)(IO.File.ReadAllText("\HVAC.json"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.  I didn't include the whole json file because it is pretty long.

Comment: It worked, the class structure is exactly what I needed.  Need to figure out why I don't have the "Paste Special" in my VS 2015 install.

Comment: You have to have a class code file open first. Don't forget to mark the answer with the checkbox to the left.