# How to add to a "sub dictionary" in a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, nested

I currently have json that looks like this:

```
{
  "Ebay": {
    "international": {
      "singles": 308,
      "bundle batches": 87,
      "multiples": 30,
      "mixed multis": 47
    },
    "first class": {
      "mixed multis": 9,
      "singles": 94,
      "multiples": 12,
      "bundle batches": 13
    },
    "singles": {
      "all": 1246
    },
    "multiples": {
      "all": 84
    },
    "over 15.5": {
      "multiples": 40,
      "singles": 9,
      "mixed multis": 62,
      "bundle batches": 8
    },
    "bundle batches": {
      "all": 135
    },
    "mixed multis": {
      "all": 66
    },
    "priority": {
      "singles": 16,
      "bundle batches": 5,
      "mixed multis": 3,
      "multiples": 2
    },
    "high value": {
      "multiples": 1,
      "bundle batches": 19,
      "singles": 3
    },
    "apo/fpo": {
      "singles": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I also have it broken down in vb like this:

```
    Dim data As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))))(mystring)
```

that breaks it apart fine, but what I'm wondering is how can I see if like "mixed multis" appears under the "high value" branch, if it doesn't add it, but if it does, add to its existing value

I've already created this which helps on the lowest level.. but don't know how to reference a dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary

```
Private Sub addOrUpdate(dic As Dictionary(Of String, Integer), key As String, newValue As Integer)
    Dim val As Integer
    If dic.TryGetValue(key, val) Then
        dic[key] = val + newValue
    Else
        dic.Add(key, newValue)
    End If
End Sub
```

I would create it as a class or structure, but not sure how to do that when the keys aren't always standard.. i.e. "international", "apo/fpo" they aren't always there,

thank you in advance

Comment: `I would create it as a class or structure, but not sure...` Using a class (not structure) if a value isnt there it would just have the default value.  A class would be easier to navigate just because Intellisense will display members as you type

Comment: honestly, VERY  new to vb (coding in it for a little over 2 weeks), I code in php primarily, and gcc, but I'm trying to learn new thing,  I'm not sure how I would go about creating a class or structure properly, especially considering that I don't know all of the possible variations that could appear in this json..

Comment: VS will create it for you: [Deserialize using VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42090483/1070452)  As for knowing what might be in it, if the API docs dont tell you that, you could add them as you encounter them

Answer (score 0):

Try using .ContainsKey, if it does not contain the key you could then create the dictionary per level of your data.