# Reading data from JSon in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, linq

I'm using Newtonsoft.JSon.Linq and at this point im kinda confused about how to make things work in the way i need it for my project. In order to jump into topic heres what im doing or at least want to do.

I want to extract the JSon data into structures based on the second level of the JSon nodes for a JSon which has this structure:

```
{
"country" : {
    "germany" : {
        "capital" : "berlin",
        "inhabitants_in_million" : 82,
        "zip-codes" : [
            [
                "berlin",
                10115

            ],
            [
                "hamburg",
                21145
            ],
            [
                "munich",
                80331
            ]
        ]
        },
    "france" : {
        "capital" : "paris",
        "inhabitants_in_million" : 67,
        "zip-codes" : [
            [
                "paris",
                75001
            ],
            [
                "marseille",
                13000
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

My Structure so far is like that so far:

```
    Public countries As List(Of country)

Public Structure country

    Public name As String
    Public capital As String
    Public inhabtitants As Integer

End Structure
```

And im using this code to read the data of the JSon:

```
Private Sub json_sub()
    For Each n In json_object
        For Each n_2 As JProperty In n.Value
            Dim c As New country

            c.name = n_2.Name
            c.capital = json_object.SelectToken("country").SelectToken(n_2.Name).SelectToken("capital")
            c.inhabtitants = json_object.SelectToken("country").SelectToken(n_2.Name).SelectToken("inhabitants_in_million")

            countries.Add(c)

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

But im somehow struggling with the data serialized in [] since its an array and all my attempts so far did not work off. I browsed for quite some time and read about deserializiation but unfortunately im kinda stuck at this point now.

My goal is to add the values from this arrays into a string which should look like:

`berlin,10115;hamburg,21145;munich,80331`

So I can add this string to my structure country with

```
Public zip_codes As String
```

Instead of using an array which is unhandy in my project at this point. I hope anyone can get me suggestion how i can achieve this.

Sincerly,
boon

Comment: Copy that json into your clipboard, and then in visual studio go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes. That should make a class you can deserialize the json string straight into, and access its properties by name. Then you can glue whatever properties you want together in a string, or better yet add a property to the class that returns the string you want

Comment: the actual json is like 25mb in size
the one i posted here is just an example of how the json looks like in dimensions

the program acutally reads the json from the *.json and converts it to an object so how do i proceed in this case since importing the json as whole does not work for me as i need to import the json on a dayly base to update a sql database

Comment: it also reults about a few million conflicts due to creating namespaces multiple times since there are a few more nodes above the and the json contains multiple datasets for every "country" in each of those

Comment: What you are trying to do in that code is create a collection by parsing it - easier to deserialize it.  That JSON is invalid by the way.  [Deserialize using JSon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42088220/1070452)

Comment: i edited the json

Comment: i edited the json. is there a way to parse this [] array somehow ? since deserializing does create tons of problems