# how to filter a specific part of a json string

Tags: json, vb.net

ive been working on json for about 2 days and its all new to me so im learning as i go i have this string im working with

```
{
    "elements": [{
        "id": "123",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "testname",
        "sku": "1234",
        "price": 2499,
        "priceType": "FIXED",
        "defaultTaxRates": true,
        "cost": 1299,
        "isRevenue": true,
        "stockCount": 0,
        "itemStock": {
            "item": {
                "id": "123"
            },
            "stockCount": 3,
            "quantity": 3.0
        },
        "modifiedTime": 1504112254000
    }],
    "href": "http://api.server.com/items"
}
```

i am usnig the Newtonsoft.Json library

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1
    Dim token = ""
    Dim url = "https://api.Server.com/"
    Dim mid = ""

    Dim parm1 = ""
    Dim parm2 = ""
    Dim parm3 = ""
    Dim parm = parm1 & parm2 & parm3

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim jsonURL As String = url & mid & "/items?" & parm

        Dim reader As StreamReader
        Dim errorMsg As String = Nothing

        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(jsonURL), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)

            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim jsonStr As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            Dim JsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonStr)
            Dim jsonArray As JArray = JArray.Parse(JsonObject.SelectToken("elements").ToString)
            For Each items As JObject In jsonArray
                Dim product As item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of item)(items.ToString)

                idTxtbox.Text = product.id
                hiddenTxtbox.Text = product.hidden
                nameTxtbox.Text = product.name
                skuTxtbox.Text = product.sku
                priceTxtbox.Text = product.price
                priceTypeTxtbox.Text = product.priceType
                defaultTaxRatesTxtbox.Text = product.defaultTaxRates
                CostTxtbox.Text = product.cost
                isRevenueTxtbox.Text = product.isRevenue
                stockCountTxtbox.Text = product.stockCount

                For Each itema In product.itemStock
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(itema("itemStock"))
                Next

                modifiedTimeTxtbox.Text = product.modifiedTime

                MsgBox("")

            Next
        Catch ex As WebException
            errorMsg = "Download failed. The response from the server was: " +
                   CType(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + errorMsg)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class

Class item
    Public id As String
    Public hidden As String
    Public name As String
    Public sku As String
    Public price As String
    Public priceType As String
    Public defaultTaxRates As String
    Public cost As String
    Public isRevenue As String
    Public stockCount As String
    'Public itemStock As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    'Public itemStock As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Public Property itemStock() As IList(Of String)
        Get
            Return m_itemStock
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As IList(Of String))
            m_itemStock = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_itemStock As IList(Of String)
    Public modifiedTime As String


End Class
```

i can get all the values of the first group of data but cant seems the "stockCount": 3 to show up any idea how i can phrase this?

sorry if im not super clear if you need more info i will try to provide it

i have updated the code of what i have so far i have gotten the  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to work but still cant seem to get the values of

```
"itemStock": {
                "item": {
                    "id": "123"
                },
                "stockCount": 3,
                "quantity": 3.0
            },
```

to populate in listbox1.items

i receive this error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be

Comment: If you have a class and it is correct, just deserialize it rather than parsing it

Comment: BTW that JSON is not complete/valid.  You probably clipped some opening or closing braces

Comment: thank you i have tried to deserialize it before but the methods ive tried all seamed to fail

Comment: If you post the valid JSON and explain how deserializing "seemed to fail", maybe someone could help. [Deserialize using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090483/1070452)

Comment: i relaized when i chopped the json i forgot a bracket and deleted a " here it is

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CEgdByYB there it is it looks better for formatting

Comment: Info pertinent to the question needs to be in the post.  You can post a link as well if you have formatting issues, but links die and questions are supposed to remain complete for The Ages.  [Deserialize using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090483/1070452)

Comment: i didnt see the edit button i updated the code with what i have so far

Comment: Your `ItemStock` is not a string, but a type (class).  Did you follow the advice in the link I have posted twice so far?  VS will create the classes for you with minor changes to array/list types